# Coding challenge optimization

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I am participating in a coding challenge that consistes in the following:

We start with a number(size of the string) followed by a string (ex: 5WWFAE) by stdin.
The letters given represent elements, F-fire, W-water, E-earth, A-air. Fire and Water cancel each other  and Earth and Air cancel as well.

The goal is to simplify the string by canceling the elements and print it, but you can only cancel adjacent members, for example: "7AFEAWWE" would result in "AWE".

In this challenge the points are given depending on how fast the program runs and how little memory you spend, somehow some people still have more points than me. Could you help-me optimising it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define stack_is_empty() stack_index == -1
#define stack_push() stack[++stack_index] = c
#define stack_pop() --stack_index

#define can_join() (stack[stack_index] + c == 'F' + 'W') || (stack[stack_index] + c == 'A' + 'E')

void process_string(int len)
{
    char c;
    char *stack = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    register int stack_index = -1;
    register int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%c", &c);

        if (stack_is_empty())
        {
            stack_push();
        }
        else if (can_join())
        {
            stack_pop();
        }
        else
        {
            stack_push();
        }
    }

    printf("%*.*s\n", stack_index + 1, stack_index + 1, stack);
}

int main()
{
    int len;

    //* Input:
    scanf("%d", &len);
    if (len == 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }

    process_string(len);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could try a Finit State Machine. You'll need about five states.

Comment: You could replace `printf` by `puts`. And using a VLA instead of `malloc` might help as long as you don't have to handle really long sequences. don't forget to terminate your string if you try this.

Comment: Initialize the stack with a single character that cannot join with the allowed characters, and then remove the `stack_is_empty` test because the stack will never be empty. At the end, do not print that initial character.

Comment: Compile with optimization turned on. Test different optimization switches, such as `-Os` and `-O3`.

Comment: Use `c = getchar();`, not `scanf("%c", &c);`.

Comment: Keep the top of stack character in a variable, say `t`, so that the `can_join` test can be changed to `t + c == 'F' + 'W' || t + c == 'A' + 'E'`, instead of having nominal array lookups. To do this, whenever a character is pushed, copy it to `t`. Whenever the stack is popped, copy the new top of stack to `t`.

Comment: Use `fwrite` (and a final `putchar('\n');`), not `printf`.